# Regex matching into multiple groups per line?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex to be able to parse the following type of strings into groups.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="[!PageTitle!]" href="[!SiteRoot!]/feed.xml" />
```

My regular expression is:

```
\[\!(.+)\!\]
```

The problem with this expression is that it seems to pull it all into 1 group:

Found 1 match:

1. "[!PageTitle!]" href="[!SiteRoot!]" has 1 group:

   ```
    1. "PageTitle!]" href="[!SiteRoot"
   ```

I want dont want the regex to continue...am I missing a boundary?  Ideally I want it to **find 2 groups**,

[!PageTitle!]

and

[!SiteRoot!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
\[\!(.+?)\!\]
```

the `+` quantifier is greedy, so will match as far as possible in the line, capturing the first [ followed by the last ] in the line. `+?` is the non-greedy equivalent.

As an aside, I'm using [Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/). I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works ok :)

```
\[!(\w+)!\]
```